# is it ok to replace count(*) with count(1) in N1ql

Tags: sql, couchbase, sql++

There is scenario where i am counting all records in n1ql using

```
Select count(*) from bucket where type='xyz' and column1='abc'.
```

Which taking around 25 sec but if i replace it with `count(1)` it takes 19sec.
My question can we use `count(1)` instead of `count(*)`. I believe it only counts only one column total counts rather than counting all. Let me know if this is not the case in n1ql.

Comment: i dont think there is any measurable statistics which says that count(1) is better than count(*), to be fair, i am not a couchbase expert to comment on this. However I remember having discussions of this kind pre Oracle 8i days. It was never true to begin with!. Semantically, count(*) is meaningful it says count all records, count(1) means count the number of 1's in your table?

Comment: You can probably answer this yourself. Are the results the same? Also see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/62576)

Comment: It's a long standing but nonetheless wrong myth that `count(1)` is faster than `count(*)`. In your  case the second execution of the query likely got the data from the cache (which was filled by the first query).

Comment: You can also try `sum(1)` for comparison. But I agree with @a_horse_with_no_name - ad hoc timings only give an indication of performance, but to increase their significance, run both queries several times to warm up the cache, then run each one a few times at a quiet time and use the middle value of each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using CB 5.0 and above COUNT(*) and COUNT(1) are treated same.

The following should perform better.

```
CREATE INDEX ix1 ON bucket(column1) WHERE type = "xyz";
SELECT COUNT(1) AS cnt
FROM bucket
WHERE type='xyz' AND column1='abc';
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Focus on `count(1)`. the database engine traverses the entire table, but does not take a value from it. The server layer puts a number "1" in each row and returns, judges that it cannot be empty, and accumulate by row.
2. Focus on `count(*)`.It needs to read the data from the disk and then accumulate the count. The database engine stores the total number of rows in a table on disk, so executing count(*) will directly return this number of rows. If you use `count(*)`, no  fields will be taken, and no value will be taken.Because it is accumulated by rows. The database has been optimized specifically for it.
3. You can also `count(PRIMARY KEY Id)`. The Id returned by the database engine involves parsing data rows and copying field values.
4. Or you can also `count(Field)`. If this "field" is defined as not null, read this field from the record line by line, judge that it cannot be null, and add up by line; if this "field" definition is allowed to be null, then when it is executed, it is judged that there is It may be null, and we need to take out the value and judge again, and accumulate if it is not null.

**Finally**, let's sort the efficiency:
`count(*)>=count(1)>count(id)>count(field)`